# rqworker timeout

Tags: python, django, redis

I am using django-rq to handle some long-running tasks on my django site.  These tasks trip the 180 second timeout of the (I assume) rqworker:

```
JobTimeoutException: Job exceeded maximum timeout value (180 seconds).
```

How can I increase this timeout value?  I've tried adding --timeout 360 to the rqworker command but this isn't recognized.

In my python code, my long-running job is called via

```
        django_rq.enqueue(
            populate_trends,
            self,
        )
```

and have tried

```
        django_rq.enqueue_call(
            func=populate_trends,
            args=(self,),
            timeout=3600,
        )
```

which I noticed in the [rq docs](http://python-rq.org/docs/) but django-rq has no such method it seems.

**Update**

For now I forked django-rq and added a [placeholder fix](https://github.com/EATechnologies/django-rq/commit/fbf0c366fa094082f307a9688f058e582fb403c8) to increase the timeout.  Probably need to work with the project to get a longer term solution.  I've started an [issue](https://github.com/ui/django-rq/issues/16) there to discuss.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This seems to be the right way to approach the problem.

```
queue = django_rq.get_queue('default')
queue.enqueue(populate_trends, args=(self,), timeout=500)
```

If you need to pass kwargs,

```
queue = django_rq.get_queue('default')
queue.enqueue(populate_trends, args=(self,), kwargs={'x': 1,}, timeout=500)
```

Thanks to the selwin at the django-rq project for the help.

Comment: If you're using RQ 1.0 (2019-04-06) or newer use **job_timeout** instead of **timeout**! [RQ Changelog](https://github.com/rq/rq/blob/master/CHANGES.md#10-2019-04-06)

Answer (score 9):

An update:
You can pass the timeout parameter as keyword argument to the @job decorator of django-rq. Notice that you have to pass the queue name argument first.

```
@job("default", timeout=600)
def long_running_task():
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Use **`job_timeout`**:

```
queue.enqueue(worker_func, *args, **kwargs, job_timeout=200)
```

---

As it has been pointed out by [Stephen Blair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/680521/stephen-blair) the `timeout` parameter doesn't work for newer versions of rq:

> `timeout` argument on `queue.enqueue()` has been deprecated in favor
> of `job_timeout`.

*https://github.com/rq/rq/blob/master/CHANGES.md#10-2019-04-06*

Where `job_timeout` has just the same effect as `timeout` had.

Answer (score 1):

For clarity for people using functions with arguments, You can pass the timeout as below

```
 string_to_print = "Hello World"

 queue = django_rq.get_queue('default')
 queue.enqueue(print_input, to_print=string_to_print, timeout=600)
```

for a function taking arguments like below

```
 @job
 def print_input(to_print):
     print "The input supplied is ", to_print
```